# Add different class to div depending on which li is clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Using Elegant Themes' Divi tabs module. Want to change the background of the containing section depending on which tab is selected.

What is happening with the code I've cobbled together is that .pink is being added to the #industryTabs div regardless of which li has the .et_pb_tab_active class on it (see screenshot):
[image]
So when I click tab 1 the background is still pink. Also noted that li.et_pb_tab_1 doesn't do anything even when li.et_pb_tab_0 is not present in my script.

Can someone help me to understand what I'm missing here, and if there is a more efficient way to do this please?

**jQuery:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            if (jQuery("li.et_pb_tab_0").hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
                jQuery("#industryTabs").addClass('pink');
            }

            if (jQuery("li.et_pb_tab_1").hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
                jQuery("#industryTabs").addClass('purple')
            }
        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="industryTabs" class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_3 et_section_regular pink">

    <ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix" style="min-height: 48px;">
            <li class="et_pb_tab_0 et_pb_tab_active"><a href="#">healthcare</a></li>
            <li class="et_pb_tab_1"><a href="#">industrial</a></li>
            <li class="et_pb_tab_2"><a href="#">technology</a></li>
            <li class="et_pb_tab_3"><a href="#">finance</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(In the interest of time/space I removed non-vital html, but #industryTabs is 5 levels up from my list items, so not a direct parent.)

**Also tried adding removeClass**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            if (jQuery("li.et_pb_tab_0").hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
                jQuery("#industryTabs").addClass('pink').removeClass('purple');
            }

            if (jQuery("li.et_pb_tab_1").hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
                jQuery("#industryTabs").addClass('purple').removeClass('pink')
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You're jQuery works - you just start with the pink class there already: [with pink class removed and added through the active tab](https://jsfiddle.net/ezr1sng8/), [with purple class added through active tab](https://jsfiddle.net/ezr1sng8/1/) - perhaps you just need to remember to remove any classes already there

Comment: Well that's befuddling, it works in the fiddle but not on my site. Tried adding   and it still just sticks on the pink. Clicking tab one doesn't switch the #industryTabs class to purple..

Comment: Added .removeClass and it still applies the pink class when I click on li.et_pb_tab_1. Is there a reset or something that I'm missing when you're looking for classes that might activate after a click?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 2:

Had a slightly better approach after I posted your example. I didn't like the idea of removing all color classes (it will exponentially grow with the amount of tabs) so I changed it to a single removeClass with no parameters to remove ALL classes for that element and then add back whatever is appropriate. Still think there is a better more efficient way I can't think of right now.

```
$('#industryTabs').removeClass();
$('#industryTabs').addClass('pink');
$('#industryTabs').addClass('et_pb_tab_0');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9sayy2w/2/

EDIT:

Modified example to assign different colors every time you click on a "tab".

https://jsfiddle.net/k9sayy2w/1/

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
   $('.et_pb_tabs_controls li').each(function(i){
         $(this).removeClass('et_pb_tab_active');
   });
   $(this).addClass('et_pb_tab_active');

   $('.et_pb_tabs_controls li').each(function(i){
     if($(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_0') && $(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('yellow');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('red');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('purple');        
        $('#industryTabs').addClass('pink');
     }           
     if($(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_1') && $(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('pink');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('red');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('yellow');        
        $('#industryTabs').addClass('purple');
     }           
     if($(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_2') && $(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('pink');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('red');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('purple');        
        $('#industryTabs').addClass('yellow');
     }           
     if($(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_3') && $(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('pink');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('yellow');
        $('#industryTabs').removeClass('purple');        
        $('#industryTabs').addClass('red');
     }           
   });
})
```

This what I would do:

Check every li and look for the active class, if it has it do whatever you need to do:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.et_pb_tabs_controls li').each(function(i){
              if($(this).hasClass('et_pb_tab_active')){
                    alert($(this).text() + ' is active');
              }
            });
        });
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k9sayy2w/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately I don't think this will work because I'm looking for different classes among my list items. When one of those classes is active then the addClass to the containing div is supposed to be added.

Comment: The code was meant to be as an example, anyway, I just modified it so you can use it to exactly what you need. Let me know if this is not what you are after and I can modify it. There are better ways to handle the removal/adding of the color classes but right now this is the best I can do. Hope it helps!